# Maya: Mystery Wireframe

Tags: 3d, maya

I am starting out with Maya and just moved my object up to reveal a mystery grey wireframe which I can't work out what it is at all. It appears I can't select or interact with it at all.

I have been playing predominantly with UV Maps, potential cause?

What is it? And how can I hide/remove it?

[image]

Comment: Did you accidentally duplicate your mesh at one point? Or were you working in NURBS?

Comment: How would I be able to tell if I duplicated the mesh? I've not touched NURBS.

Comment: I think its called the Object window or something? It should show you all the objects in your scene. I haven't touched Maya in like 5 years, tho.

Comment: @JoshKahane - I made my comment an answer. You can and mark it as accepted to close out the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you have a copy of your mesh in a `Reference layer`.

Click the layer window and if you have a layer marked with a `R` next to it, click that two more times and you'll be able to select your object.